# Error con vagrant up

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

Hola me sale este error y no se como continuar:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'machine1' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> machine1: Box 'puphpet/ubuntu1604-x64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    machine1: Box Provider: virtualbox
    machine1: Box Version: >= 0
==> machine1: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> machine1: Adding box 'puphpet/ubuntu1604-x64' (v0) for provider: virtualbox
    machine1: Downloading: false
    machine1:
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

Couldn't open file /G:/puphpet/sR2uXM/false
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el **[recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)** y lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Por favor revisa [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). También puedes buscar preguntas similares, como [esta](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23874260/4092887). Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a crearlo así:

- Crear carpeta donde vayas a tener el box

  `$ mkdir machine1`
- Situarnos en la carpeta "machine1" y crear archivo Vagrantfile

  `$ cd machine1 ; vagrant init puphpet/ubuntu1604-x64`
- Descargar box

  `$ vagrant up --provider virtualbox`

Comment: Gracias pro tu aporte Aaron CC y [bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour).